# C# condicion siempre ingresa al if

Tags: c#

Buenas tengo un inconveniente con esta porción de código, cualquier valor que tome reader simpre ingresa al if y nuca va por el lado del else, lo que necesito es que si el resultado de reader.Read() es false vaya por el else, me puede ayudar? gracias

```
  SqlCommand commandSelect = new SqlCommand(querySelect, conn);
            SqlDataReader reader = commandSelect.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.Read())
            {
                lbFVA.Text = reader["FVA_NDA"].ToString();
                lbNCA.Text = reader["NCA"].ToString();
                lbFVB.Text = reader["FVB_NDB"].ToString();
                lbNCB.Text = reader["NCB"].ToString();
            }else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No se encontraron datos", "ControlNroFiscal",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
```

ESta es la consulta que uso:

```
 select  (select max(cast(RIGHT(invoiceid,6)AS BIGINT))  from CUSTINVOICETrans R where INVOICEID like 'FVA2020-%' or INVOICEID like 'NDA2020-%')AS 'FVA_NDA', (select max(cast(RIGHT(invoiceid,6)AS BIGINT))  from CUSTINVOICETrans R where INVOICEID like 'FVB2020-%' or INVOICEID like 'NDB2020-%')AS 'FVB_NDB', (select max(cast(RIGHT(invoiceid,6)AS BIGINT))  from CUSTINVOICETrans R where INVOICEID like 'NCA2020-%' )AS 'NCA', (select max(cast(RIGHT(invoiceid,6)AS BIGINT))  from CUSTINVOICETrans R where INVOICEID like 'NCB2020-%' )AS 'NCB'
```

Comment: El `Read()` devolver true si hay al menos un registro, ya que puede posicionar e cursosr en este para su lectura. No se la querySelect que defines pero deberias asignarle un parametro que haga que no retorne ningun registro

Comment: con el querySelect lo que obtengo es un numero máximo de un listado de numeros facturas, ese numero se asigna a las variable lbFVA por ej y lo muestra. lo que sucede es que cuando asigno un valor de busqueda que se que no arroja datos y la condicion deberia ser falsa e ir  por else, sigue ingresando por el if y nunca mustra que hubo error.

Comment: que el `reader.Read()` te retorne false depende del resultado de tu query, ¿Cuantas filas te arroja tu query? si la respuesta es 1 o mas, jamás entrará al else

Comment: podrias poner el codigo de como es el SELECT que ejecutas?

Comment: si controle la consulta y siempre escribe una fila ya sea con datos o con null.

Comment: tener la query sirve pero lo importante es saber cuantas filas te retorna esa query, el SqlDataReader navega a través de las filas de la respuesta, entonces si haces un Read, te pone en la fila 1 y si haces otro Read te pone en la fila 2, así hasta el final de las filas, una vez llegues al final y no queden mas filas ahí recién te retornará false, es por eso que para que entre en ese else, tu query inicialemnte debe devolver 0 filas en caso contrario siempre entrará al if

Comment: En definitiva, parece un tema de datos (siempre te está regresando al menos un registro).
¿Has intentado ejecutar la consulta directa en la BD para el caso en que no esperas datos y ver si realmente no regresa registros?

Comment: controle la consulta y si siempre arroja una linea, si es si datos el contenido es null pero escribe una linea y por eso ingresar siempre en el if, hay alguna forma de corregir esto? porque lo qe hice fue solo comparar si es null imprima 0 y si es distinto el valor real

Answer (score 2):

intenta cambiando el if con un while. por lo general, el comportamiento de while es iterar bajo una condicion, en este caso si el reader se tiene algo que leer.

```
 while(reader.Read()){
        /* has algo*/
 }
```

o puedes llenar un datatable.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable()
dt.load(reader);
if(dt.Row.Count > 0)
{
  lbFVA.Text = dt.Row[0].Field<int>("FVA_NDA").toString();
}else{
 MessageBox.Show("No se encontraron datos", "ControlNroFiscal",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

Saludos!

Comment: no veo que tiene que ver el `while` cuando esta asignando controles simples, se supone que solo accede a un unico registro

Comment: el reader es mas performante que un datatable, porque le sugieres que lo cambie ?

Comment: @LeandroTuttini SqlDataReader da una forma de recorrer el resultado de una query según sus filas, el resultado de una query puede tener `0 o n filas`, de hecho un while es la forma más lógica de recorrer un SqlDataReader.

Comment: Como indica @LeandroTuttini, el uso de DataTable no es la mejor opción por el overhead en rendimiento y recursos (memoria).

Answer (score 1):

Tu codigo deberia ser algo como esto

```
string querySelect = @"SELECT FVA_NDA, NCA, FVB_NDB, NCB 
                        FROM tabla WHERE columna = @param1";
SqlCommand commandSelect = new SqlCommand(querySelect, conn);
commandSelect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", valor);

SqlDataReader reader = commandSelect.ExecuteReader();

if (reader.Read())
{
    lbFVA.Text = reader["FVA_NDA"].ToString();
    lbNCA.Text = reader["NCA"].ToString();
    lbFVB.Text = reader["FVB_NDB"].ToString();
    lbNCB.Text = reader["NCB"].ToString();
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("No se encontraron datos", "ControlNroFiscal",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

como observas

- se usa siempre parametros para el filtro
- no usas ninguna funciona que aplique una formaula como ser el sum, max, etc porque esta retornara siempre un resultado

Comment: Cuando dices que las funciones de agregación (como sum o max) retornan siempre un resultado eso es falso, retornan n resultados según los registros de la tabla acorde a las agrupaciones que le demos a la función de agregación

Comment: @LPZadkiel creo que quiso decir al menos un resultado, o al menos eso interprete yo..

Comment: eso si uso agrupacion, yo apuntaba a algo como ser `SELECT MAX(id) from tabla`

Comment: pues incluso en una consulta sencilla como la que pones de ejemplo eso es falso, ¿Qué sucede si la tabla está vacía? te devolverá 0 filas como resultado, en otras palabras te devolverá nada lo que de nuevo implica que tu sentencia sea falsa.